# How to Create Two Foreign Keys in One Table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'd like to build a Rails app to compare distances. Based on a comment about having a `Distance` table contain two foreign keys to `Location`, I've created the example below.

The `Locations` table will keep a record of the location name. The `Distance` table will keep two locations and a distance between them.

```
# Locations
| id     | name         |
| :----- | :----------- |
| 1      | location_1   |
| 2      | location_2   |
| 3      | location_3   |

# Distance
| id     | location_id  | location_id  | distance |
| :----- | :----------- | :----------- | :------- |
| 1      | 1            | 2            | 6        |
| 2      | 1            | 3            | 13       |
```

How do I create two foreign keys in one table? By running `rails generate model Distance distance:integer location:references` I only get one `location_id`.

Comment: do you have a sample of code ? You can use active record callback for it.

Comment: Or change your data model. Have two tables: locations and distances where distances has two foreign keys to locations.

Comment: I've updated the question based on the "two tables" comment.

Comment: I'm guessing the distance between Location1 and Location2 is the same as the distance between Location2 and Location1 so you don't need both in your distance table.  If you have a rule where the location1_id < location2_id in the Distance table  (they need to be different field names) you can look up the correct record and not have any duplicate distances.